# How to monitor JMS queue within Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am currently develop a JMS module for a spring application, now i need a simple page to monitor the traffic within the queue.

From [this](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html) page from ActiveMQ I found how to bind a broker inside the application but it lack of the details about how to integrate it with Spring MVC and any API available about it. Please give a hint.

Comment: what exactly do you want to monitor?

Comment: @guido Just like what ActiveMQ provides in the web console, so that can take a look of how many messages are in the queue and what are they..

Comment: @guido just like an implementation of the web console so that user can monitor the queue within the application

Comment: HAve you tried [hermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this method.

```
public String checkQueue(String queue) {
    return jmsTemplate.browse(queue, (session, browser) -> {
        Enumeration<?> messages = browser.getEnumeration();
        int total = 0;
        while (messages.hasMoreElements()) {
            messages.nextElement();
            total++;
        }
        return String.format("Total '%d elements waiting in %s", total, queue);
    });
}
```